# Xposed Module "Three Steps Ahead" Crashed on Android 7.0

Tags: android, crash, logcat, xposed

On my ZTE Blade v8 Mini running Android 7.0 I installed Magisk, Xposed Framework for Magisk v89 and Xposed module [Three Steps Ahead](https://github.com/spezifisch/ThreeStepsAhead) (missing in official repository). Rebooted my device and could see the module activated in Xposed Installer. When I launch the module either from within Xposed or as usual Android app it crashes endlessly. I installed Logcat Extreme and recorded the app's logs:

```
08-24 09:59:45.149  1486  5663 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.github.spezifisch.threestepsahead/.MainActivity bnds=[184,638][360,828] (has extras)} from uid 10029 on display 0

08-24 09:59:45.190  1486  1874 I ActivityManager: Start proc 7884:com.github.spezifisch.threestepsahead/u0a121 for activity com.github.spezifisch.threestepsahead/.MainActivity

08-24 09:59:45.219  7884  7884 W System  : ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.github.spezifisch.threestepsahead-1/lib/arm64

08-24 09:59:45.224  7884  7884 I Xposed  : com.github.spezifisch.threestepsahead app loaded

08-24 09:59:45.261  7884  7884 I XLua.Xposed: Loaded com.github.spezifisch.threestepsahead:10121

08-24 09:59:45.603  7884  7884 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.github.spezifisch.threestepsahead, PID: 7884

08-24 09:59:45.603  7884  7884 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.github.spezifisch.threestepsahead/com.github.spezifisch.threestepsahead.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: MODE_WORLD_READABLE no longer supported

08-24 09:59:45.603  7884  7884 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.github.spezifisch.threestepsahead.SettingsStorage.<init>(SettingsStorage.java:74)

08-24 09:59:45.603  7884  7884 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.github.spezifisch.threestepsahead.SettingsStorage.getSettingsStorage(SettingsStorage.java:49)

08-24 09:59:45.603  7884  7884 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.github.spezifisch.threestepsahead.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:70)

08-24 09:59:45.607  1486  2466 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.github.spezifisch.threestepsahead/.MainActivity

08-24 09:59:46.111  1486  1523 W ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{4666c9b u0 com.github.spezifisch.threestepsahead/.MainActivity t572 f}

08-24 09:59:46.423  1486  1530 I WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=Starting com.github.spezifisch.threestepsahead) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2027 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:882 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeLocked:1449 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2659 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:365 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.finishExit:566 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowAnimator.stepAnimationLocked:434 com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.updateAppWindowsLocked:176 

08-24 09:59:50.651  1486  2466 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.github.spezifisch.threestepsahead/.MainActivity

08-24 09:59:50.651  1486  2466 I ActivityManager: Killing 7884:com.github.spezifisch.threestepsahead/u0a121 (adj 900): crash

08-24 09:59:50.663  1486  1524 I WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=Application Error: com.github.spezifisch.threestepsahead) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2027 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:882 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeLocked:1449 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2659 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2617 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2486 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindow:2481 com.android.server.wm.Session.remove:196 

08-24 10:04:53.198  1486  2581 I ActivityManager: Start proc 8119:com.github.spezifisch.threestepsahead/u0a121 for service com.github.spezifisch.threestepsahead/.JoystickService

08-24 10:04:53.221  8119  8119 W System  : ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.github.spezifisch.threestepsahead-1/lib/arm64

08-24 10:04:53.226  8119  8119 I Xposed  : com.github.spezifisch.threestepsahead app loaded

08-24 10:04:53.256  8119  8119 I XLua.Xposed: Loaded com.github.spezifisch.threestepsahead:10121
```

Can anyone help me to figure out why the module/app crashing and how to fix it?

P.S. It also crashes on any 8.x and 9.x devices I tried

Comment: Questions about topics other than development or programming, but related to Android, are not on-topic for Stack Overflow, but may be on-topic at https://android.stackexchange.com (and you're more likely to get a good answer there).  Please review [what types of questions are on-topic in that community](//android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before posting there to ensure that your question is on-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should use Context.MODE_PRIVATE and it will work!